# How to update a value of scope in another controller

Tags: angularjs

I have two controllers and a factory. I'm trying to update a value in the factory from controller1 to see updated on controller2. Controller2 is the controller for my sidebar.

Controller 1:

```
$scope.proyectoLoad = ProyectoLoadedFactory.getProyectoLoaded();    

$scope.setDefault = function () {            
  $scope.proyectoLoad = $("#valueProyecto").val();           
  $("#small").modal("hide");
};

$scope.$watch('proyectoLoad', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    ProyectoLoadedFactory.setProyectoLoaded(newValue);
}, true);
```

Factory

```
var proyectoLoaded = -1;
var returnFactory = {
    getProyectoLoaded: function () {
        return proyectoLoaded;
    },
    setProyectoLoaded: function (idProyecto) {
        proyectoLoaded = idProyecto;            
    }
};
return returnFactory;
```

And Controller 2:

```
$scope.proyectoLoaded = ProyectoLoadedFactory.getProyectoLoaded();
        $scope.$watch(ProyectoLoadedFactory.getProyectoLoaded(), function (oldValue, newValue) {
            $scope.proyectoLoaded = newValue;
        }, true);
```

My factory is updating its value but on Controller 2 i don't see any changes.. it keeps -1 value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ahh..using jquery in controller is bad pattern in angular

Comment: thanks @pankajparkar, i'm new in angular... i have an hidden input on my view, that is fulfilled when i open a bootstrap model. Is there any way to get that hidden input with angular and not jquery?. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getters and setters are getting in the way of the 2-way binding...

Simplify your factory so it just manages a value in the return object

```
var proyectoLoaded = -1;
var returnFactory = {
    proyectoLoaded: proyectoLoaded
};
return returnFactory;
```

Then your Controller2 can be simplified to just assigning the object returned from your factory to the scope...

```
$scope.proyectoLoaded = ProyectoLoadedFactory;
```

Now when a value on that object changes in the factory, that change will be seen in your controller.

Here's a sample [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVPpeO?editors=101)

Comment: And how can i set proyectoLoaded value from first controller?

Comment: similar fashion to controller2.  make sure you assign the object returned from the factory to the scope (and not just the object's key/value).  then you can change the value on that object and it should propagate through.

Comment: I've changed my factory and put just like you said, but with that way i just can get proyectoLoaded but no set it... Am i wrong?

Comment: is there anyway to keep the factory values when i refresh the view with F5 and not to set it -1 again?